# When to use plural and singular forms in the consequence of words

Tags: singular-vs-plural, plural-forms

For example, I have figures.

What's the right form to speak about their colors?

1. Figures colors (I assume it means that I have multiple figures and each of them has a different color)
2. Figure colors (I assume it means that I have single figures painted in different colors)

The next example is more complicated.
Let's say I have boxes for figures.

What's the right form to speak about names of boxes?

1. Figures boxes colors (multiple figures, multiple boxes each of ones has some color)
2. Figure boxes colors (single figure, multiple boxes each of ones has some color)
3. Figure box colors (single figure, single box painted in different colors)

Could you help me figure out, am I correct?

**The context.**

I need to figure out the name for the variables that contains:

1. The colors of different figures (my variant is "figures colors")
2. The colors of boxes for different figures (my variant is "figures boxes colors")

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by 'figures'; presumably small models rather than numerals. All of your expressions sound strange - we would say _the colours of the figures, the colours of the boxes, boxes of [blue] figures_.

Comment: Also, can you clarify the context? By using only a few words rather than a sentence, it sounds like perhaps you're providing labels, headlines, or captions. Is this the case? If not, could you give a full-sentence example of how you're using them?

Comment: Yes, it's small models. And you correct, I use them to name the variables in the computer program.

Actually, I want to figure out principle. But my concrete case is the name for entity (variable) that contains the colors of boxes with figures and the colors of figures.

Comment: I'm not sure this question is properly On Topic if the only "context" OP can give us is that he's looking for help coming up with variable names for some specific ENUMs that he wants to code up. In fact, I'm rapidly convincing myself it's **Off** Topic.

Comment: What's context do you need then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

THere is a cross-linguistic principle that when a noun is used to modify another noun phrase it tends to lose inflections (case, number etc).

In English, nouns no longer have case endings, so this applies only to number: plural marking. So *usually* (though not always) a noun used as a qualifier is in singular form.

So in your example (which won't make much sense to readers without a lot of context) you want *figure colours*.

(An example where a plural is used is in the phrase *solids model(l)ing*. The software company I used to work for did this, and we called it *solid modelling*; but some of our competitors preferred to say *solids modelling*, to emphasise that it was modelling of solids as opposed to a solid kind of modelling.)

Comment: I've added the context. Is it helpful?

Comment: No. I'm saying that your phrase _figure colours_ is unlikely to be used by a native speaker, and without any context won't even be clearly understood (as in the comments on your question). But if you have already been talking about your figures and their colours, and especially if there are some other colours in the discourse as well, then referring to _the figure colours_ will be quite clear. So, I'm not talking about a context in which people reading this question can understand your intention, but a context in which the unusual form might be motivated.

Comment: I can't write TheColoursOfBoxesWithFigures, and I'm trying to find the form, that would be shorter and would be pretty much correct grammatically. My attempts:
TheColoursOfBoxesWithFigures -> ColoursOfBoxesWithFigures ->BoxesWithFiguresColours -> FiguresBoxesColours

Comment: Why didn't you say your problem was variable naming? That has little to do with grammar of natural languages. _FigureBoxColours_ is a perfrectly normal and comprehensible variable name.

Comment: It has to do with grammar, because I don't understand why FiguresBoxesColours is incorrect form, and FigureBoxColours is correct form. 

In my native language if I want to describe the set of colors that has each of boxes I would say: цвета (plural) коробок (plural). If the boxes have a same color I would to say: цвет (single) коробок (plural). If there will be only one box painted with a single color I would to say: цвет (single) коробки (single). If there will be only one box painted with multiple colors, I would to say: цвета (plural) коробки (single).

Comment: English no longer has a genitive case (or any other cases, except for personal pronouns) so the parallel from Russian is irrelevant. If you call your variabe _FiguresBoxesColours_, nobody will object, but native English speakers will guess that it was named by somebody who was not a native English speaker. In English a sequence like _figure box colour_ is more like a compound noun - in German it would be written as one word - and the convention is that qualifying words are not in the plural form unless this is necessary to distinguish another possible meaning.

Comment: Thank you very much! Now it's become much more clearly for me. I've googled the some terms, that you used and found this rule: "In forming the plurals of compound terms, pluralize the significant word. If both words are of equal significance, pluralize both. Pluralize the last one if no one word is significant in itself".
https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tcdnstyl-chap?lang=eng&lettr=chapsect2&info0=2.16

It's pretty unusually for me, but I will try to remember it at least.